# Creating 30+ stripe plans, issue with scaling

Tags: php, scalability, stripe-payments

So I am using stripe to allow my customers to do recurring billing (on-demand cleaners), the problem I have that at the moment there are 30+ plans a user could be assigned to depending on their inputs. For example:

**User 1:**

- Cleaning interval = every 4 weeks
- House size - 4 bed

*plan = A*

**User 2**

- Cleaning interval = every 6 weeks
- House size - 2 bed

*plan = B*

The above example has loads of permutations, so obviously as we get bigger and we move countries the permutations become greater.

Now my solution to scalability was to create a plan per user (would this scale to 100k plans in stripe)?

The second solution was to do token based payments and setup a cron or something similar to process it (how easy would it be)

I am using PHP, so any solution would more than likely be done in this

I would love some feedback or even case studies on how to solve this

Oliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stripe does not restrict the number of plans you can create, so you could potentially have tens of thousands of different plans.

However, that doesn't seem like a very good solution. What you could do instead is use the "[metered billing](https://support.stripe.com/questions/metered-subscription-billing)" payment flow:

- [Create a plan](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan) for $0 / month (or whatever interval you want to use)
- [Create subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) to bind customers to this plan
- At the end of each billing period, a new invoice will be automatically created and an [`invoice.created`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.created) event will be sent. Using [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks), you could catch this event on your server and [create invoice items](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_invoiceitem) for the actual amount you want to bill.
- Approximately one hour later, the invoice will be closed and payment will be attempted. Depending on the result, either an [`invoice.payment_succeeded`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.payment_succeeded) or [`invoice.payment_failed`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#event_types-invoice.payment_failed) event will be sent.
- If the payment fails, it will be retried according to your [subscription settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/recurring).

Since it seems you have different billing intervals, you might need to create a few different plans (all for $0, but with different intervals), but the general idea still applies.

Comment: That is pretty awesome, I will have to look into that. I hope Laravel Cashier supports metered billing, I won't accept it as an answer just yet. I want to see some other solutions first :)

Comment: No problem. To be clear, I work for Stripe, and I've seen accounts with a _lot_ of plans/coupons/etc. It's not an issue for Stripe, it's just that it might be a pain to manage on your end.

Comment: yeah, I noticed that. It's really cool that stripe has someone checking such sites to offer a good source of information. I really dig your company